# What is the maximum number of records returned by getData method

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

I would like to create my own connector in Google Apps Script. Is there any limitation of processing and returning number of records by [getData()](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/build#fetch_and_return_data_with_getdata) method?

Answer (score 3):

getData() supports returning up to 1 million records/rows.

Link: https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/reference#getdata

Answer (score -3):

There is no documented limit. To get the whole data from a sheet, you can use `sheet.getDataRange().getValues()`. If you get data in multiple calls like `sheet.getRange('A1').getValues()`, `sheet.getRange('A2').getValues()` and so on, it will make your script very slow and may timeout and script has 5 minute run time limit.
It is advised you get the data from spreadsheet in just one call for performance reasons.

Edit:
The run time limit is now updated. You can check it [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas)

Comment: The question is about a [tag:google-data-studio] method, not one from [tag:google-spreadsheet]